# TextView background null when not set in layout

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand why a `View`'s background can be *null* and how that makes sense. **Shouldn't there be at least be a default background (ie *transparent*) that is inherited from the parent view or something?**

For example, the following `TextView`'s background attribute is omitted, which results in `Background` (`getBackground()`) being *null*

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/null_bg_tv"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  <!--android:background="@color/black"-->

TextView tv = v.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.null_bg_tv);
tv.Background.SetTintList(_csl);  // null exception
```

---

**Update**

A comparison of object dumps show they only differed by a few fields

**No background specified** (android:background="@null")

> Background= 
>   HasOverlappingRendering=False 
>   IsOpaque=False

**android:background="@color/black"**

> Background=android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable@5c3246d 
>   HasOverlappingRendering=True 
>   IsOpaque=True

Comment: It returns null because Null basically means empty like there's nothing in it and as Nothing is stored in `android:background`, how can it return something. The = operator used is basically assign something on the right to something on the left and if it's not used on `android:background` as in this case, how can you get something in return?

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar For some context, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47043218/tinting-a-list-items-viewgroup-vs-a-contained-textview

Comment: "Shouldn't there be at least be a default background..." – No. If a `View` doesn't have a background, it just won't draw anything for it, and will be essentially transparent. "For some context, please see..." – In that question, `v` has a `background` set already in the layout – `android:background="#FFFFFFFF"` – so its `Background` won't be null. `tv` doesn't have one set, however, so its is null.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar Many times during an objects construction, it's members are initialized with non-null default values. Here, I was wondering why the `TextView` did not "inherit" the containing `View`'s background (either by a *reference* or *deep* copy) during inflation.

Comment: It would be inefficient for every single view in a hierarchy to have it's background explicitly constructed, especially if they all have the same exact data.

Answer (score 0):

> [**Applying Styles and Themes to the UI**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/themes.html)
>   There are several ways to set a style:
>
> - To an individual view, by adding the style attribute to a View element in the XML for your layout.
> - To an individual view, by passing the style resource identifier to a View constructor. This is available for apps that target Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.
> - Or, to an entire activity or app, by adding the android:theme attribute to the  or  element in the Android manifest.
>
> When you apply a style to a single View in the layout, the attributes defined by the style are applied only to that View. If a style is applied to a ViewGroup, the child View elements don't inherit the style attributes; only the element to which you directly apply the style applies its attributes. However, **you can apply a style so that it applies to all View elements—by applying the style as a theme.**